# how to pass the index variable of a for loop to anonymous Thread/Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, file, for-loop, io

I've searched for similar questions but they were not involving for-loops.
I've got the following code:

```
    image = new BufferedImage[maxFiles];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxFiles; i++) {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {                 
                try {
                    file = new File("0" + i + ".jpg");
                    image[i] = ImageIO.read(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        };
    }
```

As you can see I want to load every image file by its own thread to optimize a bit.
Unfortunately the variable **i** of the for loop can't be passed through the **run** method and I can't either make it final or static. How would you solve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many files is `maxFiles`?  Creating an unbounded number of threads all at one time usually is a bad idea.  Have you considered using a _thread pool_ instead?

Answer (score 6):

You can have a final variable with the same value.

```
image = new BufferedImage[maxFiles];
for (int i = 0; i < maxFiles; i++) {
    final int index = i;
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {                 
            try {
                file = new File("0" + index + ".jpg");
                image[index] = ImageIO.read(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    };
}
```

You probably also want to start your threads.

Comment: you are surprisingly right; I wonder if there was a better way instead of initializing **maxFiles** int variables... it's just the language's fault apparently, and yes, I forgot to write the run() call here.

Comment: @mmalkavian You want to call `start()`, not `run()`. There is no point writing something as a `Thread` if you are going to call `run()` on it.